# Paths not working in ALB ingress in EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using AWS as a Cloud Provider. I want the ALB to work on a single host which is a domain that I own, I want it to open different services based on the paths and service name that I provide in the ingress file but it will not open the service at the expected page

The service should open at http://mydomain/attacker1 and http://mydomain/attacker2 attacker1 and attacker2 are 2 different services with respective service and deployment files

But I get a "page cannot be found" when I hit the page

I have deployed and configured ALB ingress controller using official docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

I have created Hosting Zones and Routes in Route 53 to propagate my Domain

I am adding my service file, deployment file and ingress file for reference

Please help me with any insights or anything I have missed in the code

```
Ingress.yaml


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: attacker-ingress
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
spec:
  # ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: www.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /attacker1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: attacker1
                port:
                  number: 30002
          - path: /attacker2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: attacker2
                port:
                  number: 30003


Deployment.yaml


---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "attacker"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "attacker1"
    replicas: 1 
    strategy: 
      type: "RollingUpdate"
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "attacker"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "attacker"
            image: "qabcr/abc"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "NODE_ENV"
                value: "development"
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 30002
        imagePullSecrets: 
          - 
            name: "secrets-development"



---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata: 
    name: "attack1"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "attacker"
  spec:
    type: NodePort 
    ports: 
      - 
        nodePort: 31400
        port: 30002
        targetPort: 30002
    selector: 
      app: "attacker"
```

Comment: Try changing `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type` to `ip`

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this?